# PyTorch LSTM not using hidden layer

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, lstm

I am using PyTorch's LSTM api, but have a bit of an issue. I'm using an LSTM for a dummy AI model. The task of the model is to return 1 if the previous number is less than the current one.

So for an array like `[0.7, 0.3, 0.9, 0.99]`, the expected outputs are `[1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0]`. The first output should be `1.0` no matter what.

I designed the following network to try this problem:

```py
# network.py

import torch

N_INPUT = 1
N_STACKS = 1
N_HIDDEN = 3

LR = 0.001


class Network(torch.nn.Module):

    # params: self
    def __init__(self):
        super(Network, self).__init__()

        self.lstm = torch.nn.LSTM(
            input_size=N_INPUT,
            hidden_size=N_HIDDEN,
            num_layers=N_STACKS,
        )

        self.linear = torch.nn.Linear(N_HIDDEN, 1)
        self.relu = torch.nn.ReLU()

        self.optim = torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=LR)
        self.loss = torch.nn.MSELoss()

    # params: self, predicted, expecteds
    def backprop(self, xs, es):

        # perform backprop
        self.optim.zero_grad()
        l = self.loss(xs, torch.tensor(es))
        l.backward()
        self.optim.step()

        return l

    # params: self, data (as a python array)
    def forward(self, dat):

        out, _ = self.lstm(torch.tensor(dat))

        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.linear(out)

        return out
```

And I am calling this from this file:

```py
# main.py

import network

import numpy as np

# create a new network
n: network.Network = network.Network()


# create some data
def rand_array():

    # a bunch of random numbers
    a = [[np.random.uniform(0, 1)] for i in range(1000)]

    # now, our expected value is 0 if the previous number is greater, and 1 else
    expected = [0.0 if a[i - 1][0] > a[i][0] else 1.0 for i in range(len(a))]
    expected[0] = 1.0  # make the first element always just 1.0

    return [a, expected]


# a bunch of random arrays
data = [rand_array() for i in range(1000)]

# 100 epochs
for i in range(100):
    for i in data:

        pred = n(i[0])
        loss = n.backprop(pred, i[1])
        print("Loss: {:.5f}".format(loss))
```

Now, when I run this program, I'm just getting a loss around `0.25`, and it isn't really changing once it gets there. I think the model is just picking the average value of `0` and `1` (`0.5`) for each input.

This leads me to the belief that the model can't see the previous data; the data is just random numbers (the expected output is based on these random numbers, though), and the model can't remember what happened before.

What is my issue?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a hidden state issue. You're using a weird setup which is probably hindering learning.

First we want a proper dataset/dataloader

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
import numpy as np
import torch.nn.functional as F

class RandDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, sequence_length):
        self.sequence_length = sequence_length
    
    def __len__(self):
        return 10000 # data is generated so length is arbitrary 
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        sequence = torch.rand(self.sequence_length)
        labels = torch.ones_like(sequence)
        labels[1:] = sequence[:-1] < sequence[1:]
        
        sequence = sequence[None,:,None] # shape (1, sequence_length, 1)
        labels = labels[None,:] # shape (1, sequence_length)
        
        return sequence, labels

def collate_fn(batch):
    sequences = torch.cat([i[0] for i in batch])
    labels = torch.cat([i[1] for i in batch])
    return sequences, labels

dataset = RandDataset(1000)
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=32, collate_fn=collate_fn)
```

Now the model. Add an input projection layer, remove the unnecessary relu after the lstm module.

```py
class LSTMModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_in, d_proj, d_hidden, n_layers):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.input_layer = nn.Linear(d_in, d_proj)
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=d_proj, hidden_size=d_hidden, num_layers=n_layers, batch_first=True)
        self.output_layer = nn.Linear(d_hidden, 1)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.input_layer(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        
        x, _ = self.lstm(x)
        
        x = self.output_layer(x)
        return x

model = LSTMModel(1, 32, 64, 2)
```

Now we set up training. We're predicting a binary output, so we want to use `BCEWithLogitsLoss` rather than `MSELoss`. Using MSE for categorical prediction doesn't make sense.

```py
device = 'cuda'

opt = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-3)
loss_function = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()

epochs = 1

model.to(device);

for epoch in range(epochs):
    for i, batch in enumerate(dataloader):
        seqs, labs = batch
        
        seqs = seqs.to(device)
        labs = labs.to(device)
        
        preds = model(seqs)
        loss = loss_function(preds.reshape(-1), labs.reshape(-1))
        
        if i%10==0:
            print(f'{loss.item():.3f}')
        
        opt.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        opt.step()
```

After training, test performance

```py
model.eval()
seq, lab = dataset[0]

pred = model(seq.to(device)).cpu()

pred = (torch.sigmoid(pred)>0.5).float().squeeze()
lab = lab.squeeze()

acc = (pred == lab).float().mean()
print(acc)
> tensor(0.9990)
```